# Задание источников света и материала

Tags: c++, opengl

Какими функциями в OpenGL задается удаленный, сферический и цилиндрический источники света? И этот же вопрос про материал, не пропускающий свет и с отражением.

Облазила весь интернет, что-то находила, но именно таких названий нигде не вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> удаленный, сферический и цилиндрический источники света?

Чего??? Бывают только точечный (светит во все стороны), направленный (параллельный) и spot light (конусом).

Скачай себе OpenGL суперкнигу(последнее издание на русском - 3-е) и почитай. Там есть эти темы.

Тип источника света зависит от параметров, установленных функцией glLight*. Подробнее ищи в Интернете или в книгах. В том же NeHe должно это быть.

Comment: удаленный, сферический и цилиндрический источники света именно так нам препод дал в задании, вот и я думаю, что он имел в виду

Comment: А он объяснял, что это такое? Если нет, то он не должен был задавать это задание. Возможно, он имел в виду, что это не тип источника света, а то, как он выглядит? Если просто задать свет, то сам источник не будет виден, поэтому надо что-то нарисовать на его месте. Только этому противоречит слово "удалённый". Удалённый источник света - это другое название направленного источника. Он находится бесконечно далеко, поэтому нарисовать на его месте ничего нельзя.

 Можно узнать исходный текст задания? Подозреваю, что какая-та информация исказилась.

Comment: вот именно, что он не объяснял
Задание: 
Источники света должны быть такие:
а)  удаленный, цвет cyan (голубой), координаты (15,0,-20);
б)  сферический, цвет magenta (пурпурный), координаты (15,-20,10);
в)  цилиндрический, цвет white (белый), координаты (0,0,20).
Материалов должно быть два вида: не пропускающий свет и с отражением.